# HBase Java connection

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to Setup a connection to HBase via Java, but I'm facing an issue. I installed a single node HDP 2.1 via Ambari on my CentOS 6.5. I have following code:

```
public class PutExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      final String serverFQDN = "hadoop.hortonworks";

      Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
      conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", serverFQDN); 
      conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
      conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");

      HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);

      try {

          HTable table = new HTable(conf, "hb_tt2");

      } catch ( Exception ex ) {
          System.out.println("Error caught.");
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println("End.");
   }
}
```

And this is the Output :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/bae/Desktop/Neue%20Bibliotheken/lib%20Hadoop/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/bae/Desktop/Neue%20Bibliotheken/lib%20Zookeeper/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Error caught.
java.io.IOException: Unable to determine ZooKeeper ensemble
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.<init>(ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher(ConnectionManager.java:1725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.isTableOnlineState(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isTableDisabled(ConnectionManager.java:926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.relocateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:159)
    at bt.PutExample.main(PutExample.java:41)
End.
```

I have not changed any config-files, and i use the jar-files which i found on the Hadoop-Server. Am i missing any configs in my program or at the Server? I can't fihure out what this error-message means.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the version of the hbase jars. Sometimes minor changes help.
I had the same exception and modifying the hbase client jars (in pom.xml) from 0.98 to 0.98.4 helped.

```
<version>0.98.4-hadoop2</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all needed jars to HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Try this string to execute your jar

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hbase classpath` hadoop jar your.jar PutExample
```